# postfix&dovecot -- adding some spam filter

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have setup my SMTP server (on a Linux/Ubuntu 15.04 VPS rented at OVH) according to http://www.binarytides.com/install-postfix-dovecot-debian/ 
(so there is no traditional user on the box; hence it looks like a naive installation of procmail is not relevant)

Any clues about adding some spam filter using free software only (with an ideological preference for GPLv3+ or LGPLv3+ ones)?

Some additional wishes:

I would like a possible web interface (to unblock some emails filtered as spam) but I profoundly dislike PHP.  My web server is nginx.

I probably am interested in also using spamoracle (or some Bayesian machine learning filter).

I am willing to code a tiny thing which could help.

I'm a bit afraid to do wrong. It is an active server for my family MX domain @starynkevitch.net and I am getting all my personal emails there, and it is also used by my family (about a dozen persons).

Answer (score 2):

I finally am using SpamAssassin.

I followed the advice (in French, sorry for that) on http://artisan.karma-lab.net/ajouter-spamassassin-postfix

but I have the following script in `/etc/postfix/basile-spamassassin.sh`

```
# voir http://artisan.karma-lab.net/ajouter-spamassassin-postfix
# par Basile
logger -t basile-spamassassin "debut $@"

while getopts "f:" opt;do
case $opt in
    f) FROM="$OPTARG";;
esac
done
/usr/bin/spamc  | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f $FROM "$@"
exit $?
```